# How to disable free shipping based on custom product attributes?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, shipping, shipping-methods, custom-attributes

I want to disable free shipping...if I select a product with some custom attribute...is there any way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That is a bit of complicated process you should create a module for it and check for couple of thing. Show what you have done so far, then it is easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new Js file to check out page.
app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <!-- Add local resources -->
        <script src="VendorName_ModuleName::js/checkout.js"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <move element="logo" destination="porto_header"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

only add script inside head tag  after page tag.

```
head>
        <script src="VendorName_ModuleName::js/checkout.js"/>
   head
```

now add this file here.

app/code/vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/web/js/checkout.js

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 10);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 50);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 100);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 200);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 500);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 1500);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 2500);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 5000);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 10000);
setTimeout(function(){ 
    hidefreeshipping();
 }, 20000);
function hidefreeshipping(){
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: "../check_attribute_data/fetchdata",
        cache: false,
        async : false,
        data:{},
        type: "POST",
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(response){
            
            if(response=='yes'){
                    jQuery('.table-checkout-shipping-method:nth-child(2)').css('display':'none');
                   }
                    
               
                 
            //console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Now for ajax action url add this file.
app/code/vendorname/modulname/Controller/Fetchdata.php

```
<?php
namespace vendorname\modulname\Controller;

class Fetchdata extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $product_attribut_exists='No';
        //run foreach loop on cart items and check attribute of products, 
        //if attribute exist change $product_attribut_exists='Yes
        echo $product_attribut_exists;
        
    }
}
```

for publick URL, you can use this file.

app/code/vendorname/modulename/etc/frontend/routes.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="check_attribute_data" frontName="check_attribute_data">
            <module name="vendorname_modulename" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Now in browser, run this url http://yourmagentourl.com/fetch_rest_api_data/fetchdata i-e http://yourmagentourl.com/RoutFrontName/ControllerName

Answer (score 0):

If you using Magento default **Free Shipping** `\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping`  Shipping method then you can try below solution.

Create a after plugin on `\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping::collectRates`

And check here you the custom attribute of the product and return false if condition match

**Create di.xml**

Create `di.xml` at `app/code/StackExchange/MagentoTest/etc/di.xml` and declare plugin class.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="StackExchange_MagentoTest_Plugin_Magento_OfflineShipping_Model_Carrier_Freeshipping" sortOrder="10" type="StackExchange\MagentoTest\Plugin\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**Create Plugin class at `app/code/StackExchange/MagentoTest/Plugin/Magento/OfflineShipping/Model/Carrier/Freeshipping.php`**.

**And Define the plugin class here.**

```
<?php
namespace StackExchange\MagentoTest\Plugin\Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;

class Freeshipping
{

    public function afterCollectRates(
        \Magento\OfflineShipping\Model\Carrier\Freeshipping $subject,
        $result,
        RateRequest $request
    ) {

       if($result instanceof  \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result){
           $check = false;
           foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item) {
               if ($item->getParentItem()) {
                   continue;
               }
               $attributeValue = $item->getProduct()->getYOUR_ATTRIBUTECODE();
               // here condition match
               if({YourCondition}){
                   $check = true;
                   break;
               }

               /*
               if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately()) {
                   foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                       if ($child->getProduct()->isVirtual()) {

                       }
                   }
               }*/
           }

           /**
            * If check variable is true return  false.
            * False means hide Free Shipping method at Checkout
            */
           if($check){
               return false;
           }
       }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:-
first create a custom module using below link https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/

now follow up form here

**vendor/module/etc/di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="Vendor_Module_Plugin_Magento_Shipping_Model_Shipping" sortOrder="10" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model\FreeShipping"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

now create **freeshipping.php** file

**Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Magento\Shipping\Model;
class FreeShipping
{
    protected $product;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product
    ) {
        $this->product = $product; 
    }
 
    public function aroundCollectCarrierRates(
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Shipping $subject,
        \Closure $proceed,
        $carrierCode,
        $request
    ) {
        $noFreeShipping = false;
        $allItems = $request->getAllItems();
         
        // iterate all cart products to check if no_free_shipping is true
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {    
            $_product = $this->product->create()->load($item->getProduct()->getId());
            // if product has no_free_shipping true
            if ($_product->getNoFreeShipping()) {
                $noFreeShipping = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        // if no_free_shipping is yes and shipping method free shipping return nothing
        if ($noFreeShipping && $carrierCode == 'freeshipping') {
            return false;
        }
        $result = $proceed($carrierCode, $request);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Now you just need to create a custom attribute on which you will disable the free shipping for selected products

**Vendor\Module\Setup\InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        /**
         * Add attributes to the eav/attribute
         */

        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
                \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                'no_free_shipping',
                [
                    'group' => 'General',
                    'type' => 'int',
                    'backend' => '',
                    'frontend' => '',
                    'label' => 'no_free_shipping',
                    'input' => 'boolean',
                    'class' => '',
                    'source' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean::class,
                    'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => false,
                    'user_defined' => false,
                    'default' => '1',
                    'searchable' => false,
                    'filterable' => false,
                    'comparable' => false,
                    'visible_on_front' => false,
                    'used_in_product_listing' => false,
                    'unique' => false,
                    'apply_to' => 'simple,configurable,bundle'
                ]
            );
    }
}
```

you are done